# How can you change the bubbles size on Torque in CartoDB

Tags: carto, torque

Is there any way to change the size of the bubbles on Torque (min-max)?

Comment: This follows up a closely related question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82492/using-different-collors-on-torque-cartodb.

Answer (score 2):

Bubble size is defined by, `marker-width`. So a simple Torque style would be (pulling from your previous question),

```
Map {
-torque-frame-count:128;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"time_column";
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:"cumulative";
}

#table_name {
   marker-width: 12;
   marker-opacity: 0.9;
   marker-allow-overlap: true;
   marker-placement: point;
   marker-type: ellipse;
   marker-line-width: 2;
   marker-line-color: #ffffff;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
}
```

If you have a visualization where the bubbles grow or shrink over time, those are defined in the frame-offset rules. For example,

```
#table_name[frame-offset=1] {
   marker-width:12.5;
   marker-opacity:0.45; 
}
#table_name[frame-offset=2] {
   marker-width:14.5;
   marker-opacity:0.225; 
}
```

So here, `frame-offset=2` would be the last frame the bubble is drawn in, and therefor is the biggest at 14.5 pixels