# Category colors on torque

Tags: carto, torque

I’m trying to create a torque viz on the CartoDB dashboard following this StackExchange post: [Using different colors on Torque CartoDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82492/using-different-colors-on-torque-cartodb/83430#83430)

I followed that answer, but my marker colors are still all the same.

SQL and CartoCSS are below, and here is a link to the viz: https://pgrasmussen.cartodb.com/viz/c3b82e78-8f4f-11e3-8156-0e625a1c94a6/map

Any ideas?

SQL

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN type='Theft' THEN 1
WHEN type='Accident' THEN 3
WHEN type='Vandalism' THEN 7
END as type_number
FROM damage_nigeria
```

CartoCSS

```
/** torque visualization */
Map {
-torque-frame-count:512;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"cartodb_id";
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#damage_nigeria_viz{
  comp-op: lighter;
  marker-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 1.5;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  marker-fill: green;

}
#damage_nigeria_viz[frame-offset=1] {
  marker-width:8;
  marker-opacity:0.45; 
}
#damage_nigeria_viz[frame-offset=2] {
  marker-width:10;
  marker-opacity:0.225; 
}
#damage_nigeria_viz[value=3] {
  marker-fill: red; 
}
#damage_nigeria_viz[value=7] {
  marker-fill: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the tutorial: https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/wiki/How-spatial-aggregation-works you will see that the aggregation should change to:

```
-torque-aggregation-function: "round(avg(type))";
```

instead of

```
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
```